# Skip column when inserting into MySQL

Tags: mysql, insert

How can I skip a column when inserting a new row into a table **without knowing neither the names nor the amount of columns** in my table?

Using `INSERT (col1, col2) VALUES (1, 2)` is **not an option**, because I can not know the amount of columns during runtime. It's all calculated from user input.

Thus, I need to skip the first column (`id`, PRIMARY KEY auto_increment) when inserting.

Comment: set the value to Null.  Wouldn't that be the same as skipping it since it would be null unless there's triggers...  wait a second.. how can you not know the number of columns  unless you're dynamically creating the table at runtime... are you?

Comment: Why is it not an option? If user input lets you decide *what* to insert, it must be sufficient to calculate *how* to insert it. In other words, if you know that you are inserting 1 into col1 and 2 into col2, that's enough to construct a parameterized statement dynamically, bind values 1 and 2 to its parameters, and execute it against your mysql instance.

Comment: Because it would mean creating two loops to build the query - the first one to build the part before `VALUES` and a second to insert the actual values

Comment: If you don't know the names or the amount of columns in your table you're going to struggle to construct any INSERT statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can insert without giving column names, but you had to give some values for all columns.

```
INSERT INTO comments 
VALUES (null, 2, 3, 4,null,6) 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `imageid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `uid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `content` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `adate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `ids` (`imageid`,`adate`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1  ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try inserting 0 as the first value. If the column is auto-incremented it should work.

From MySQL reference:
"No value was specified for the AUTO_INCREMENT column, so MySQL assigned sequence numbers automatically. You can also explicitly assign NULL or 0 to the column to generate sequence numbers.
"
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 0):

You can just input in a one liner like this:

The first column is parentID so I'm skipping that and going straight to student:

```
INSERT into Lib_Book(guardian, studentFN, studentLN, year) VALUES ('Father','Joe', 'Gitter','2019');
```