# incorrect input Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php

```
<?php

$fname= $_REQUEST['firstname'];
$lname= $_REQUEST['lastname'];
$email= $_REQUEST['email'];
$pass = $_REQUEST['password'];

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect ');
}
$ins1 = "INSERT into signup values( '$fname' , '$lname', '$email','$pass')";


$select = mysql_select_db('ait', $conn);
if(! $select)
{
    die("<h2> incorrect input <h2>".mysql_error());
    header('location:index.php');

}

$in1 = mysql_query($ins1);
if (!$in1)
{
    die("<h2> incorrect input <h2>".mysql_error());
    header('location:signed.php');
}


mysql_close($conn);
header('location:signed.php');
exit;
?>
```

I am making a sign up form and adding this in the database but I am getting this error "incorrect input  Column count doesn't match value count at row 1". I am not inserting id from this code as it is auto increment.

Comment: Show `signup` table structure.

Comment: Try specifying the column names explicitly in the query.  `INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES (value1, value2)`  Also, be aware that your code is *wide open* to **SQL injection**.  You're treating user input as code and executing anything your users send you.

Comment: I am new to PHP programming and still learning. So I need to learn more about SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write down the names of columns explicitly in the query.

```
INSERT into signup(first_name,last_name,email,password) 
values( '$fname' , '$lname', '$email','$pass')
```

Took at look at SQL injection. Passing parameters like this is not a safe approach.

Answer (score 0):

If `id` is autoincrement (and it is the only column you skip and the first one in the table), use:

```
$sql = "INSERT into signup values (null, '$fname' , '$lname', '$email','$pass')";
```

This way, you let `mysql` fill in the id value, but you still need to specify it.

An alternative is to use:

```
$sql = "INSERT into signup (col1, col2, col3, col4) values ('$fname' , '$lname', '$email','$pass')";
```

Where you replace `col*` with the actual column names.

Comment: How did you know that there is only 1 column missing and it is nullable?

Comment: because Op said: "I am not inserting id from this code as it is auto increment."

Comment: And usually, the id column is the first one added to a table.

Comment: Have you tried it yourself? if `id` is autoincrement (and pk), you *can* set it to null in the insert and it gets populated correctly.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo, see this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163540/skip-column-when-inserting-into-mysql. And the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html